# Identify this electronic part

Tags: motherboard

Please if anybody can identify this electronic part as it is burnt and I need to replace it. Your help will so much appreciated!
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: What is the board from (what product)?  The closest I came was a transient voltage suppression diode (Surface Mount – 400W > SMAJ series. Electrical Characteristics. Part ... 16C. 13.60. 15.20)  .  If that is what it is, you need to find the fault before replacing it.

Comment: i'd be very tempted to say if you don't have the skillset to identify it, you don't have the skillset to replace it. Soldering irons & motherboards are not the best of friends.

Comment: you may get a better answer posting over here>>>>https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Motherboard" was the most suitable tag that I found available. In fact, this board is from burnt Siemens fuel mass flowmeter (Coriolis principle). Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Electrical interface RS-485, 2-wire. Supply voltage [V] 12 - 27 VDC